# android 'MapView' weather like overlay

Tags: android, android-mapview

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-A6VHppSxRyk/TrkVmkzTPDI/AAAAAAAACaQ/sEDVPWNcmIs/s293/Untitled.png

I am trying to show weather condition in my map as shown above, How can I implement this?

Comment: Can you generate the weather overlay as a bitmap?

Comment: cant say, actually i don't know how data is coming from server in KML format and how to parse that data to show overlay. any tutorial will help... Thank You

Comment: The overlay you show in https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-A6VHppSxRyk/TrkVmkzTPDI/AAAAAAAACaQ/sEDVPWNcmIs/s293/Untitled.png is a bitmap, no way you could/should generate cloud images like this client-side from vector based data

Comment: This is screen from app from Android market ::https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aws.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5hd3MuYW5kcm9pZCJd, Could you drop some light on this, Like how they achieving this map from data.?

Comment: Inherit from MapActivity, make a normal layout with the buttons etc, and a FrameLayout in the center where you in upper layer place a RelativeLayout with the two buttons and in the lower layer (the first you add) place a MapView.
In the MapView you add an overlay with a semi-transparent bitmap as shown in my answer. The bitmap you generate server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that extends Overlay and add it as overlay.
In tha class you override

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas c, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
  //super.draw(c, mapView, shadow);

  if (shadow) return; // no shadows

  Rect canvasRekt = new Rect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
  Rect kortRekt = ...

  c.drawBitmap(overlejretKort, canvasRekt, kortRekt, paint);
  c.drawRect(kortRekt, paint);
}
```

The kortRekt should contain the rectangle of your bitmap (here its called overlejretKort)

Comment: Heres a full example, showing some geological information overlayed: http://code.google.com/p/android-eksempler/source/browse/trunk/AndroidElementer/src/eks/kort/KortAktivitet.java?r=118

Comment: Note that there's some bookkeeping to do to make it overlay at the right place, and some work to load weater overlay tiles asynchroneously over the net. It took a day's fiddling to get my example to work, and it still doesent always draw the overlay in the correct place.